# Same base URL across Site Collections

Tags: site-collection, url

For growth and performance reasons, I need to distribute my Webs across several Site Collections.

Still, I want the **URL** of these Webs to appear as though they are in the same place. Here is an illustration.

I want:

- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer1234
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer4324
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer5675
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer6535

I DON'T want:

- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/**sc4**/customer1234
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/**sc4**/customer4324
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/**sc5**/customer5675
- hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/**sc5**/customer6535

etc.

Is this possible?
Any ideas?

--Raoden

Answer (score 1):

Defines a managed path for each customer, and create a site collection at each of this managed paths.

You will have to declare explicit managed paths for each customer.

Instead of /sites/*, you will have /SC1, /sc2, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I guess I was not clear enough in my description.
I want, say, customer1 and customer3 in the same Site Collection, and customer2 and customer4 in another Site Collection, but I want the URL of them all to look like this:
 •hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer1

 •hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer3

 •hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer2

 •hxxp://sharepoint/mywebapp/customer4


Any ideas?

Comment: can't you create one site collection per customer ? it will be far more easier to maintain

Comment: This is, honestly, my personal opinion too, but our customer, who will be hosting this solution, thinks that 20.000+ customer Site Collections is too much for them to administrate.
I am not an admin, but a developer, so I'm not quite sure what to make of that...

Comment: What about creating one site collection per customer, but putting them in a set of content database ? You can move sites from one content db to another later if you need

Comment: This is exactly what the customer does not want to have to do; move around on 20.000 Site Collections, one by one

Comment: a lot of operations can be scripted. Why does your customer will have to move site collection ? can't you simply fix a number of site collection per DB, and create new Dbs as the number of site collection growth ?

Comment: That would be a good way to handle it I think.
Is it possible to configure this somehow, or does it have to be monitored, and switch to a new contentDB at an appropriate time?

Comment: The only thing you can do OOB is to set the default content DB. Depending on your strategy, you can create a timer job that will create and/or set default content db when a threshold is reached. Or you can simply create powershell script and launch them manually. This depends greatly of the repartition requirements, and the amount of manual work you want to execute / avoid.